# Can't Archive/Build framework from Carthage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage, carthage

My objective-c project uses SDWebImage framework (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), I installed this framework using Carthage (https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). But when trying to configure the "Run Script" in Build Phases if I don't check the "Run script only when installing" my app doesn't work, it gives me the error saying "No such file or directory"

If I check the "Run script only when installing" I can run the app and do all development I need, but I get an error when Archiving.

When I try to Archive my app to send to Apple I'm getting the error "bin/sh: bad interpreter: no such file or directory"

[image: Run Script]

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong when trying to install my framework? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: I'm having this same issue.